# 2D Point, to 3D, then back to 2D

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics

Figure 1:
I am drawing a bezier on a layer in 2d (CoreGraphics), I have point A & B.

Figure 2:
I can rotate the layer approximately 70 degrees.

Figure 3:
I want to know what the points A & B are now, by somehow squishing the image back from 3D to 2D.

What I'd ideally want to make is a function like this:

```
-(CGPoint)calculateNewPointFrom:(CGPoint)p withAngle:(float)angle
{
    //Rotate point by angle in 3d space
    //Return new point in 2d space
}
```

[image: 2D to 3D, back to 2D]

All help welcome. Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about CoreGraphics, but this is just a geometry problem.  You need the result of applying two matrix transforms; first a *rotation*, and then a *projection*.  You can multiply these two matrices together to obtain a single transform.

Comment: Why not actually rotate the layer in 3D?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist - When I do this, the layer will have no real depth and look flat. I just want the co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If you have coordinates of a point `Q` in 3D: (x, y, z)

And you want to project it onto a plane which contains a point `P` and has normal vector n,

The equation of the plane is

```
(R - P) . n = 0
```

Where I use vector subtraction, and `.` is the dot product.

From this you can deduce the projection of any point onto that plane: you draw a line along the normal vector `n` until it intersects with the plane.

So there will be some value `a` such that

```
Q + a * n
```

lies in the plane, i.e.

```
(Q - a * n - P) . n = 0
```

Solving for a (notice that `n . n = 1` ):

```
a = (Q - P) . n
```

(notice - this is the "normal distance" from Q to P; no coincidence!)

The value of the point where they intersect is now

```
Q + ((Q - P) . n ) * n
```

Notice again - I am using vector math, so that last `*n` results in three values (since n is a 3D vector).

You can generalize this if you are trying to make a non-normal projection onto a plane (for example, you want to project onto the XY plane, but you are "looking at an angle"). In this case, you need to project along a different direction m (the direction you are looking), and the equation of the intersection becomes

```
Q + ((Q - P) . n ) * m / (m . n)
```

As you can see, if m is perpendicular to n (you are looking along the plane, rather than at it), there is no solution...

You can also see that if you are making a projection straight onto the XY plane so n = [0 0 1]), the whole thing simplifies to setting Z=0

Let me know if this is enough, or if you need actual lines of code...

> ---  EDIT  --- adding some simple code:

If you have a series of points (x, y) that describe your curve, you can rotate about the Z axis (perpendicular to your plane) by an angle θ by the following:

```
x1 = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta);
y1 = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta);
```

Now you can "squish" these points so it appears that you are looking at them from the side, by simply reducing the y coordinates:

```
x2 = x1;
y2 = y1 * cos(alpha);
```

where `alpha` is the apparent angle from which you are looking at the curve. So if you are looking directly down onto the XY plane, `alpha` is 0, and `y2 = y1`. If you look at 45 degrees, `alpha` is `pi/4` and `y2 = 0.707 * y1` (approximately).

You can combine these two transformations into:

```
xnew = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta);
ynew = cos(alpha) * (x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta));
```

Try this for a few values of theta (between 0 and 0.5, in steps of 0.1) and alpha (similar range is probably good). See if you like the result.

Maybe that is a better (in the sense of "more useful") answer for you?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this, It's a bit over my head to be honest. The first point I have is in 2d space, After I apply a rotation on the x axis, how do I get the new point in 3d space?

Comment: I have a lot of reading to do :-) Thanks for your answer, I'm sure it makes sense, but I need to do some learning. I found CGPointApplyAffineTransform, it looks like it might help me out. Thanks